# listen for both onkeyup and onchange without jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a form with `<input>` fields that when data is input into them  `.onkeyup` triggers a function. However I also have a `<select>` dropdown box and of course the browser does not fire an `.onkeyup` event when it is changed. My code is currently

```
var formInput = document.getElementById('Form');

formInput.onkeyup = function(e){
    //do stuff
}
```

how can I as well include the `.onchange` to `formInput.onkeyup` without using jquery

Comment: You should listen to input and select inside the form. Listening to the form won't do what you expect.

Comment: `formInput.onchange = ...`

Comment: @A.Meshu It will because of event bubbling.

Comment: I know `formInput.onchange` would do it @Barmar. Itrying to listen for BOTH. I know this isnt correct but something along the line of `formInput.onchange || formInput.onkeyup = fucntion(){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to both by simply assigning to both event properties.

```js
var formInput = document.getElementById('Form');

formInput.onkeyup = formInput.onchange = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  let el = e.target.id;
  console.log(`${e.type} on ${el}`);
}
```

```html
<form id="Form">
  <input type="text" id="textInput">
  <select id="menu">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Within the function, `e.type` will be either `keyup` or `change`, and `e.target` will tell you which element the event happened on.

Comment: the `.onkeyup` works when using it as you suggested. However the `.onchange` doesn't work when the dropdown is selected and changed

Comment: Nice! i didn't know that assignment is possible!

Comment: @Barmar yeah it works. I had a small typo in one of my tags that was causing the data to not propagate. I do appreciate the solution you gave me a world over. Thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Distinguish text input elements and select elements using `document.querySelector('input#Form')` and `document.querySelector('select#Form')` then u can handle their events separately

Answer (score 0):

Try `onchange` instead of `onkeyup` for the dropdown select.
I am sure the below link will be helpful for you.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: `onchange` only fires when the input loses focus. Not an option for what im doing